# Unable to Style Sanity Content using BlockContent

Tags: reactjs, codeblocks, blogs, sanity, groq

guys I need some help regarding styling my sanity content, So the issue is I'm trying to style the **code** block, but I'm not able to do so, when I style other items like h1, h2, h3, etc. then the **code** block disappers and If I'm styling **code** block then the other items are not styled.

I'm using @sanity/block-content-to-react, SyntaxtHighlighter and highlight.js.
Here's my code:

**Main Code**

```
<BlockContent
    className="blog__body"
    dataset={import.meta.env.VITE_SANITY_DATASET}
    projectId={import.meta.env.VITE_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}
    blocks={blog.body}
    serializers={serializers}
/>
```

**Serializers**

```
const serializers = {
    types: {
        code: CodeBlock,
    },
    block: (props) => {
        switch (props.node.style) {
            case "h1":
                return <Heading1>{props.children}</Heading1>;
            case "h2":
                return <Heading2>{props.children}</Heading2>;
            case "h3":
                return <Heading3>{props.children}</Heading3>;
            case "h4":
                return <Heading4>{props.children}</Heading4>;
            case "h5":
                return <Heading5>{props.children}</Heading5>;
            case "h6":
                return <Heading6>{props.children}</Heading6>;
            default:
                return <NormalText>{props.children}</NormalText>;
        }
    },
    listItem: (props) => {
        switch (props.node.listItem) {
            case "bullet":
                return <UnorderedList>{props.children}</UnorderedList>;
            case "number":
                return <OrderedList>{props.children}</OrderedList>;
            default:
                return <li>{props.children}</li>;
        }
    },
    marks: {
        link: Link,
    },
};
```

**Fetching Data from sanity** -

```
const { slug } = useParams();
const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null);
const publishedTime = timeDifference(
    new Date(),
    new Date(blog?.publishedAt)
);

useEffect(() => {
    client
        .fetch(
            `*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug]{
                _id,
                title,
                body,
                publishedAt,
                categories[]->{
                    title
                },
                author->{
                    name,
                    avatar
                },
                publishedAt,
                mainImage{
                    asset->{
                        _id,
                        url
                    },
                    alt
                },
            }[0]`,
            { slug }
        )
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.length === 0) {
                console.error(`No post found with slug "${slug}"`);
                return;
            }
            setBlog(data);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}, [slug]);
```

`

**codeblock styling**

```
function CodeBlock({ node }) {
    return (
        <SyntaxHighlighter
            language="javascript"
            style={atomDark}
            showLineNumbers
        >
            {node.code}
        </SyntaxHighlighter>
    );
}
```

Sorry if I did any mistakes but I'm asking first time here, please help.

I'm looking to solve my problem that I'm facing from a long time now, I was using sanity to display me blogs but I'm not able to style my code blocks, It would be really helpful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out, it was a small mistake, the block should go inside types alongside code.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, please [edit] your answer and include the working code.